# jQuery Mobile Reload Page Depending on Div Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and am having trouble reloading a page if the text within a div equals a certain value. The contents of the div are loaded with AJAX. The contents of the div are being updated via AJAX just fine, but I don't know why the page is not reloading when the contents are equal to "Your item has expired."

```
 $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#listitem', function(event){       
        $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){

   $('#tableHolder').load('ajax_item_time.php', function(){
       if($("#tableHolder").text() == "Your item has expired."){
         window.location.assign("mobile_list.php")
       } 
       else {
      setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
       }
   });

    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

Use `.changePage()` instead of `window.location.assign`.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#YOUR_PAGE_ID");
```

Here is the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/methods.html).